# js change style DOM elements - why this code works bad?

Tags: javascript, dom

js has big problems & is very bad.

why this code works bad??

(this is a back to top btn)

```js
function checkScrollTop(){
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 300) {
    document.getElementById("backToTop").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("backToTop").style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1);
  }else {
    document.getElementById("backToTop").style.opacity = "";
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("backToTop").style.display = "";
    }, 300);
  }
}
function backToTop(){
  var x = setInterval(function () {
    if (document.body.scrollTop != 0) {
      document.body.scrollTop -=20;
    }else {
      clearInterval(x);
    }
  }, 1);
}
```

```css
#backToTop{
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #098774;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
  <html>

<body onscroll="checkScrollTop();">
    <div id="backToTop" onclick="backToTop();">^</div>
  <div style="width: 300px;">
http://stackoverflow.com/ads/community?id=so_community_div Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?omni=Au0GHyu2P9QIOw2VALkFPwACAAAAAgA…XJlZ2lzdGVyZWR8eC1wZXJzb25hLWZyb250ZW5kfAB8cwIR0hDY2RqW&lw=1959&zc=25&pf=9 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://stackoverflow.com/ads/community?id=so_community_div Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?omni=Au0GHyu2P9QIOw2VALkFPwACAAAAAgA…XJlZ2lzdGVyZWR8eC1wZXJzb25hLWZyb250ZW5kfAB8cwIR0hDY2RqW&lw=1959&zc=25&pf=9 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://stackoverflow.com/ads/community?id=so_community_div Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?omni=Au0GHyu2P9QIOw2VALkFPwACAAAAAgA…XJlZ2lzdGVyZWR8eC1wZXJzb25hLWZyb250ZW5kfAB8cwIR0hDY2RqW&lw=1959&zc=25&pf=9 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://stackoverflow.com/ads/community?id=so_community_div Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?omni=Au0GHyu2P9QIOw2VALkFPwACAAAAAgA…XJlZ2lzdGVyZWR8eC1wZXJzb25hLWZyb250ZW5kfAB8cwIR0hDY2RqW&lw=1959&zc=25&pf=9 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://stackoverflow.com/ads/community?id=so_community_div Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?omni=Au0GHyu2P9QIOw2VALkFPwACAAAAAgA…XJlZ2lzdGVyZWR8eC1wZXJzb25hLWZyb250ZW5kfAB8cwIR0hDY2RqW&lw=1959&zc=25&pf=9 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://stackoverflow.com/ads/community?id=so_community_div Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
http://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?omni=Au0GHyu2P9QIOw2VALkFPwACAAAAAgA…XJlZ2lzdGVyZWR8eC1wZXJzb25hLWZyb250ZW5kfAB8cwIR0hDY2RqW&lw=1959&zc=25&pf=9 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER</div>
</body>
  <html>
```

view following video

[url=http://vip.opload.ir/vipdl/95/10/hamidr.bk/avc-Video-1-18-2017-7-11-11-PM.mp4 ]
http://vip.opload.ir/vipdl/95/10/hamidr.bk/avc-Video-1-18-2017-7-11-11-PM.mp4 [/url]

Comment: _js has big problems & is very bad_ really!! so why you use it.

Comment: so i use witch one language programmig for change dom??

Comment: js is very cool. you just need to learn it properly to get all of its glory.

Comment: this is back to top btn and should default opacity be 0

Comment: a scroll with arrow buttons.

Comment: why dont work fade-in animation when i scroll down??

Comment: have you tried my recommendation to write opacity=0 and display="none" ?

Comment: yes i try. but problem not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visibility instead display!

modified code:

```js
function checkScrollTop(){
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 500) {
    document.getElementById("backToTop").style.cursor = "";
    sdocument.getElementById("backToTop").style.visibility = "visible";
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("backToTop").style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1);
  }else if (selector("#backToTop").style.visibility == "visible") {
    document.getElementById("backToTop").style.opacity = "";
    document.getElementById("backToTop").style.cursor = "default";
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("backToTop").style.visibility = "";
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

```css
#backToTop{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok completely rewritten:

```
opacity=0;
window.onload=function(){
setInterval(function(){
   var el=document.getElementById("backToTop");
  if(el.style.opacity>opacity){
    el.style.opacity-=0.1;
  }else if(el.style.opacity<opacity){
    el.style.opacity+=0.1;
  }
  if(el.style.opacity>0){
    el.style.display="block";
  }else{
    el.style.display="none";
  }
  },100);
  };
```

Now you can simply do opacity=1; in your code, it will transit smooth and without flickering.

Comment: do you know why first opacity apply then display apply in video??

Comment: look this video http://vip.opload.ir/vipdl/95/10/hamidr.bk/avc-Video-1-18-2017-8-10-16-PM.mp4

Comment: look at this code (jquery) : $(function () {
 $(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > ۱۰۰) {
 $('#back-top').fadeIn();
 } else {
 $('#back-top').fadeOut();
 }
 });  this code like my code!

Comment: You know that the function will be trigerred very often -> much timeouts are created. Try the updated code

Comment: i try this code , but there is other problem http://vip.opload.ir/vipdl/95/10/hamidr.bk/avc-Video-1-18-2017-8-10-16-PM.mp4

Comment: @hamidreza: wich other programming languages do you know?

Comment: little java - php , js

Comment: if i delete display = none in js code , run well and without problem

Comment: @hamidreza: try doing this in java. By the way the worse thing about this is css. And if you delete the display thing it will work smoothly. Only problem: the user can click on it even if it is invisible...

Comment: i can set cursor = none and change onclick attribute :-) when opacity is 0

Comment: thank you jonas , but i use visibility insted display , all problems are solved